# How to wait until the keyboard is dismissed to take an action after?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using to close the keyboard using **FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus** but I want to wait to close the keyboard to make another action after so how can I wait till the keyboard is closed ?

Comment: Hi have a look on this library which very useful for listening keyboard changes. You will documentation their with example.

                                                                                                                                                                            
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility

Comment: @SyedIbrahim yes I know this package but I didn't used it yet, thanks for your response I will check it out.